# How do I create App Specific Directory (Android KITKAT 4.4+) in SECONDARY EXTERNAL STORAGE (ext-sdcard)?

Tags: android, android-sdcard

As per Android Developer website - [External Storage](https://source.android.com/devices/storage/)
Secondary external storage must not be writable by apps, except in package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions.

I am not able to create desired folder  , getting Exception 'open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)' on Android

- getExternalFilesDirs(null);  returns only primary external storage path but not Secondary external storage sd-card.

-Tablet - Lenovo , Samsung mobile

Comment: If the app specific directory is not there you cannot create it as you have no write acces to the medium. What kind of device is this?

Comment: I have exactly the same issue. Did you find a solution?

Answer (score -1):

In your **Manifest.xml**, put the following code:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: Apps must not be allowed to write to secondary external storage devices, except in their package-specific directories as allowed by synthesized permissions.

Means no need to write the permissions for APP SPECIFIC FOLDER on external secondary storage

Comment: If you want to write IN the app specific folder you do not need that permission yes. But you have no app specific storage folder yet. To create it you have to write directly on the medium. For that you would normally need a permission. But i think it will not help you in this case.

Comment: Yes , i tried my code on HTC mobile 4.4.2 , it creates app specific folder
/Android/data/com.example/test.txt on secondary external storage sd-card

but on other 4.4.2 tablet like Asus , Dell ,Lenovo .. it gives me exception

Comment: this is clearly wrong, in KitKat the WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission changed and now governs the access on PRIMARY external storage. There is no such thing for secondary external storage. @greenapps' comment is right, if there is no special home dir for your app on secondary external storage, you have no chance to create it. I guess the device vendor actively decided to not allow this